# Converting callback from C++ to C++/CX

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-cx, winrt-async

In code I am porting I have this function which takes function as an argument:

```
void doSomething(std::function<void(std::string)> callback)
```

Could you please tell me how to implement this function in C++/CX, how to convert std::function to C++/CX delegate and how to call the callback later on from C++?

Answer (score 2):

Below is sample code, I am not sure if this is exactly what you are after - but maybe you will find some usefull code.

You can use delegates and events. To convert your function to delegate you can use proxy lambda. There are some usefull samples in msdn docs: [Delegates (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755798.aspx)

```
public delegate void CallbackFunction(Platform::String^ arg);
public ref class MyCallbacks sealed {
public:
    event CallbackFunction^ callbackEvent;

    void doSomething(Platform::String^ arg) {
        callbackEvent(arg);
    }

internal:
    void doSomething(std::function<void(std::string)> callback) {
        CallbackFunction^ callbackPtr = ref new CallbackFunction(
            [=](Platform::String^ arg) {
            std::wstring tmp(arg->Data());
            std::string astr(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());//use wcstombs, MultiByteToWideChar, if such conversion is required
            callback(astr);
        });
        callbackEvent += callbackPtr;
    }
};

void test() {
    // On c++/cx side MyCallbacks initialization
    MyCallbacks^ cb = ref new MyCallbacks();

    // Here register callback functions to be raised later on
    cb->doSomething([](std::string s) {
        s.data();
    });

    // Raise callbacks from pure c++ inside c++/cx using delegetes and event
    cb->doSomething(L"DoSomething");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it possible to set callback function from pure c++ ? I would like to run C++/CX WinRT component from pure C++ passing callback as argument. Once user interact with purchase, the callback gets called from WinRT C++/CX

Comment: It should be possible, I have never tried it but I would start with WRL: here is link to get you started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973459.aspx - "How to: Activate and Use a Windows Runtime Component Using WRL". Maybe there is a simpler way, you might call func in your pure c++ library from your winrt app, and in such function return your callback.